# arduino project of conneting server to run php

Tags: arduino

he code above is running on sketch on arduino . I do not know if I set the ip and server address wrong
Please help !!!!!

I run on serial monitor to run the code. It is saying
Here is the result
connection....
connection failed

disconnected

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = {   0x91, 0xA2, 0xEA, 0x0D, 0x2B, 0xB1 };
byte ip[] = {   196, 10, 10, 94};
byte server[] = { 196, 10, 10,63};

EthernetClient client;

void setup()
{

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  delay(1000);

  Serial.println("connecting...");

  if (client.connect(server,80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    client.print("GET http://196.10.10.63:89/calls/channel.php HTTP/1.0\n");
    client.print("Host: http://196.10.10.63:89");
    client.println();
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();
    for(;;)
      ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code mentions getting a page from port 89:

```
client.print("GET http://196.10.10.63:89/calls/channel.php HTTP/1.0\n");
```

but you connect to port 80:

```
if (client.connect(server,80)) {
```

Change the port in the `connect()` to 89, if that's the right one. Also in the GET request you don't need the full URL, try the path:

```
client.print("GET /calls/channel.php HTTP/1.0\n");
client.print("Host: 196.10.10.63");
```

Comment: Yes, I changed it. But still cannot conneted successfully. my computer run on wireless,so I have wireless ip address. And the server run on ethernet. Is that right ?

Comment: Make sure that the PC has the HTTP port (89 in this case) open. Also, is the web server configured correctly? Can you open that same URL on your computer?

Comment: yet again, make sure the port is open for outside connections